# Does scottklement HTTPAPI supports 7zip or any compresion

Tags: web-services, soap, rpgle, rpg

I am using scottklement **HTTPAPI** to consume **SOAP** webservices from the back end **RPGIV** coding, the webservices is hosted on apache tomcat.

Now some of our xml SOAP is large (400000) characters and  would like to use compression for the request and response to make it faster.

Is the HTTPAPI able to handle the compression?
Is there any other methods I can use to for performance improvements.

IBM os 6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a look through the HTTPAPI code this morning I do not believe it supports any type of compression.

You can see this response on the same matter if you search for 'GZIP' (for example) on [this page](http://scottklement.com/archives/ftpapi/201307/msg00095.html):

> ... HTTPAPI does not support GZIP and downloads uncompressed data (it doesn't need to decompress so overall maybe a wash?) ...